# Why won't my c# application work?

Tags: c#

This program is supposed to get you a garfield comic from the date you entered or the daily comic.  The first button should allow you to pick a custom comic but only the daily comic (button 2) seems to work Here's the code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Garfield_Comic_Viewer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int month = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int day = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            int year = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

        switch (month)
    {
        case 1:
            month = 01;
        break;
        case 2:
        month = 02;
        break;
        case 3:
        month = 03;
        break;
        case 4:
        month = 04;
        break;
        case 5:
        month = 05;
        break;
        case 6:
        month = 06;
        break;
        case 7:
        month = 07;
        break;
        case 8:
        month = 08;
        break;
        case 9:
        month = 09;
        break;
    }
            switch (day)
        {
            case 1:
                day = 01;
                break;
            case 2:
                day = 02;
                break;
            case 3:
                day = 03;
                break;
            case 4:
                day = 04;
                break;
            case 5:
                day = 05;
                break;
            case 6:
                day = 06;
                break;
            case 7:
                day = 07;
                break;
            case 8:
                day = 08;
                break;
            case 9:
                day = 09;
                break;
        }



            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = ("http://garfield.com/uploads/strips/" +year+ "-"            +month+ "-" + day + ".jpg");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string mon = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
            string d = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
            string y = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://garfield.com/uploads/strips/" + y + "-" + mon + "-" + d + ".jpg";
 DateTime whole = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think those big `switch` blocks are actually doing anything...

Comment: Classic answer for classic question. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're expecting integers to behave like strings.

The point you're missing is that:

```
 int a = 01;
```

is the same as:

```
 int a = 1;
```

There's no difference. You can't pad an integer. What you need is to *format* the integers into a string, using a format specifier. Something like this:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = 
    string.Format("http://garfield.com/uploads/strips/{0:D4}-{1:D2}-{2:D2}.jpg", 
        year, month, day);
```

This will give a string that contains the numbers in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

(The documentation for padding string-formatted integers is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)